# No views_per_day in /info route?

Tags: support, api-v2

I'm not particularly crying over it, just curious why the views_per_day field was dropped?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

View data isn't stored in a way that makes "views over time" easy to calculate, nor is the final result reliable.

Given the move away from views elsewhere in the API (dropping sorts, fields, etc. ; for similar reasons) it seemed appropriate to drop the field from /info.

Comment: @George, ah thanks for reminding me about that. I thought the spec was on the private beta announcement, I forgot it was "draft".

Comment: Is there any suggested workaround or alternative? This is the most interesting stat for us over on travel.SE